# Problem in Extended the tableView rows with reloading the 10-10 News

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

My program works fine but the problem is I want to extend my rows with the present rows.
I have API which give me 10 news per page and i want to upadate my tableViewRows with this news title. In the Starting when i Parsed the Api with page one( IDValue used for page) first my table view is load after that UIAlert and starts the parsing after completed the parsing ([myTableView reloadData];) update the tableView with 10 news Raw but i have a 11th row which having the "Load More 10 News option" when i click on this again parsing starts but in the end i want to upadate my table view with extension of next 10 news like ( previous 10 + new 10) news = 20 news (Rows) in TableView but it give me "SIGABRT" error.

I share my .h and .m file with you plz go through this and give me the suggestions plz how can i over come this error.

Error is:

> 2011-09-20 14:28:57.278 Work[8692:207] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '** -[NSMutableArray
>   objectAtIndex:]: index 11 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]'
>   ** Call stack at first throw: (  0   CoreFoundation
>   0x013ac5a9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185    1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x01500313 objc_exception_throw + 44  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x013a20a5 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 261     3   FashionUnited
>
>   0x00005288 -[NewsMainVC tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 648   4
>
>   UIKit                               0x00673b98
>   -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal)
>   _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 634     5   UIKit
>
>   0x006694cc -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal)
>   _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 75    6   UIKit
>
>   0x0067e8cc -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:]
>   + 1561    7   UIKit                               0x0067690c
>   -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 242   8   QuartzCore
>
>   0x01e06a5a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181   9   QuartzCore
>
>   0x01e08ddc CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220    10  QuartzCore
>
>   0x01dae0b4 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310
>     11  QuartzCore                          0x01daf294
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292    12  QuartzCore
>
>   0x01daf46d
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99
>     13  CoreFoundation                      0x0138d89b
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 27    14
>   CoreFoundation                      0x013226e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
>   + 295     15  CoreFoundation                      0x012ea857
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 231    16  CoreFoundation
>   0x012ea761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97    17  GraphicsServices
>   0x019f61c4 GSEventRunModal + 217  18  GraphicsServices
>   0x019f6289 GSEventRun + 115   19  UIKit
>   0x0060cc93 UIApplicationMain + 1160   20  FashionUnited
>   0x00002d49 main + 121     21  FashionUnited
>   0x00002cc5 start + 53 ) terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'NSException'

And Extend the TableRows each time with +10 News .

.h file

NewsMainVC.h

```
@class DetailNewsDisplayController,NewsInfo,NewsParser;

@interface NewsMainVC : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> {

    int selectedLanguage;
    int currentLanguage;

    NSInteger IDValue;

    NSMutableData *responseData;

    NewsParser *parser;

    NSURL *url;
    UIAlertView *alert;
    NewsInfo *aNewsInfo;

    NSString *FinalString;
    UIAlertView *alertNext;

    UITableViewCell *nibLoadedCell;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinnerNext;

    DetailNewsDisplayController *ndvController;

    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
    UIAlertView *alertt;

    IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
    IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
    IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageLabel;
    IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;


}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIAlertView *alertt;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
@property (assign, readwrite) NSInteger IDValue;
@property (assign,readwrite) int selectedLanguage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *FinalString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *pages;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *nibLoadedCell;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSData *responseData;

-(IBAction) goToOptions:(id)sender;

- (void) parseXML;

-(NSString*) languageSelectedStringForKey:(NSString*) key;
```

.m file

```
@implementation NewsMainVC
@synthesize selectedLanguage;
@synthesize nibLoadedCell,optionPageVC,FinalString,IDValue,spinner,alertt,responseData;


extern int global;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    appDelegate = (WorkAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    IDValue = 1;
    textLabel.text=[self languageSelectedStringForKey:@"Welcome to Advance Localization"];

    NSString *mainWaitMessage = NSLocalizedString (@"Contacting Server\nPlease Wait...", @"Contacting Server\nPlease Wait...");
    alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:mainWaitMessage message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];
    [alert show];
    spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    spinner.center = CGPointMake(alert.bounds.size.width / 2, alert.bounds.size.height - 50);
    [alert addSubview:spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [myTableView reloadData];
}


#pragma ----------------------
#pragma Select APi According to selectedLanguage

-(NSString*) languageSelectedStringForKey:(NSString*) key
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"zh" ofType:@"lproj"];

    if(selectedLanguage==MGD_LANG)
    {

        FinalString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://www.xyz.com/api.php?page_id=%d",IDValue];

    }
    else if(selectedLanguage==TKY_LANG)
    {

        FinalString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://www.abc.com/api.php?page_id=%d",IDValue];

    }

     url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:FinalString];
    [FinalString release];

    // Create the Request.
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy 
                                         timeoutInterval: 30.0];
   // [url release];

    // Create the connection and send the request
    NSURLConnection *connection = 
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    // Make sure that the connection is good
    if (connection) {
        // Instantiate the responseData data structure to store to response
        self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];

    }
    else {
        NSLog (@"The connection failed");
    }

    NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
    NSString* str=[languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:nil];

    return str;

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSURLConnection delegate methods

// Called when a redirect will cause the URL of the request to change
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
             willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
            redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse
{
    NSLog (@"connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:");
    return request;
}

// Called when the server requires authentication
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSLog (@"connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:");
}

// Called when the authentication challenge is cancelled on the connection
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
didCancelAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSLog (@"connection:didCancelAuthenticationChallenge:"); 
}

// Called when the connection has enough data to create an NSURLResponse
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog (@"connection:didReceiveResponse:");
    NSLog(@"expectedContentLength: %qi", [response expectedContentLength] );
    NSLog(@"textEncodingName: %@", [response textEncodingName]);

    [self.responseData setLength:0];

}

// Called each time the connection receives a chunk of data
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog (@"connection:didReceiveData:");

    // Append the received data to our responseData property
    [self.responseData appendData:data];

}

// Called before the response is cached
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
                  willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse
{
    NSLog (@"connection:willCacheResponse:");
    // Simply return the response to cache
    return cachedResponse;
}

// Called when the connection has successfully received the complete response
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog (@"connectionDidFinishLoading:");

    // Convert the data to a string and log the response string
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] 
                                initWithData:self.responseData
                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response String: \n%@", responseString);

    [responseString release];
    [connection release];

    [self parseXML];


}

// Called when an error occurs in loading the response
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog (@"connection:didFailWithError:");
    NSLog (@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);

    [connection release];

}


- (void) parseXML{

    NSLog (@"parseXML");

    // Initialize the parser with our NSData from the RSS feed
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] 
                              initWithData:self.responseData];

    //Initialize the delegate.
    parser = [[NewsParser alloc] initXMLParser];

    //Set delegate
    [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];

    // Start the parser
    if (![xmlParser parse])
    {
        NSLog (@"An error occurred in the parsing");    
    }

    [myTableView reloadData];

    if (IDValue == 1) {
    [spinner stopAnimating];
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    }

    [xmlParser release];

}


#pragma -
#pragma TableView

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [appDelegate.newsArray count]+1;

}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *postCellId = @"postCell";
    static NSString *moreCellId = @"moreCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSUInteger count = [appDelegate.newsArray count];

    if (row == count) {

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:moreCellId];
        if (cell == nil) {

            if (cell == nil) {
                [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCell103" owner:self options:NULL];
                cell = nibLoadedCell;
            }

        }

    } else {

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:postCellId];
        if (cell == nil) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCell13" owner:self options:NULL];
            cell = nibLoadedCell;
        }

        aNewsInfo = [appDelegate.newsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        titleLabel.text = [aNewsInfo.title stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        imageLabel.image = aNewsInfo.smallImageData;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@" Global %d",global);

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSLog(@"%d",row);

    NSUInteger count = [appDelegate.newsArray count];
    NSLog(@"Ini AppDelegate Count  %d",count);

    if (row == count) {


        NSMutableArray *newPosts = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:appDelegate.newsArray];  
        NSUInteger newCount = [newPosts count];
        NSLog(@"NewPost  %d",newCount);

        selectedLanguage = global;
        IDValue = IDValue +1;
        textLabel.text=[self languageSelectedStringForKey:@"Welcome to Advance Localization"];

        if (newPosts) {
            [appDelegate.newsArray addObjectsFromArray:newPosts];

            NSUInteger countOne = [appDelegate.newsArray count];
            NSLog(@"appdelegate+newPosts %d",countOne);
            NSUInteger newCountTwo = [newPosts count];
            [newPosts release];
            NSLog(@"NewPost %d",newCountTwo);
            NSMutableArray *insertIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];

            for (NSUInteger item = newCount; item < countOne; item++) {

                [insertIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:item 
                                                               inSection:0]];
            }

            [myTableView beginUpdates];
            [myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths 
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [myTableView endUpdates];

            [myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                                  atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone 
                                          animated:YES];

            NSIndexPath *selected = [myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            if (selected) {
                [myTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selected animated:YES];
            }

        }

    }
    else {

        ndvController = [[DetailNewsDisplayController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailNewsDisplayController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        aNewsInfo = [appDelegate.newsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        ndvController.aNewsInfo = aNewsInfo;

        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:ndvController 
                                               animated:YES];
        [ndvController release];
    }
}


-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 63;
}




@end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you arereloading the tableview you have to increase the no of rows.